# Runtime error when trying to implement client-only routes in GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, routes, gatsby

I'm trying to follow the basic examples on the Gatsby website. These are my codes so far:

```js
// pages/app.js
import { Router } from '@reach/router';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import * as React from 'react';

import Browse from '../components/Browse';
import Upload from '../components/Upload';

const AppPage = () => (
  <>
    <nav>
      <Link to "/app/browse">Browse Link</Link>
      <Link to "/app/upload">Upload Link</Link>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <Router basepath="/app">
        <Browse path="/browse">Browse</Browse>
        <Upload path="/upload">Upload</Upload>
      </Router>
    </main>
  </>
);

export default AppPage;

// components/Browse.tsx
import * as React from 'react';

import { RouteComponentProps } from '@reach/router';

type BrowseProps = {
  children?: string,
} & RouteComponentProps;

const Browse = ({ children }: BrowseProps) => <div>{children}</div>;

Browse.defaultProps = {
  children: '',
};

export default Browse;

// components/Upload.tsx
// Identical to Browse.tsx, except it's named Upload
type UploadProps {...}

const Upload = ...;

export default Upload;
```

To help configure client-only paths, I'm using `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths` to help automate the process as suggested on the site. It has been added to `gatsby-config.js` like so:

```js
// gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths",
    options: {
      prefixes: ["/app/*"],
    },
  },
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-manifest",
    options: {
      icon: "src/images/icon.png",
    },
  },
]
```

As far as I can tell, that should be all I need to get it working. So I started the development server:

```
npm run develop
```

I successfully opened `http://localhost:8000/app/` and the two `Links` are successfully rendered, but when I click on either of them, a runtime error occurred:

## Unhandled Runtime Error

One unhandled runtime error found in your files. See the list below to fix it:

Error in function **eval** in **./node_modules/@gatsbyjs/reach-router/es/index.js:698**

Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

```
./node_modules/@gatsbyjs/reach-router/es/index.js:698
```

```js
 696 |       return React.Children.map(element.props.children, createRoute(basepath));
  697 |     }
> 698 |     !(element.props.path || element.props.default || element.type === Redirect) ? process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? invariant(false, "<Router>: Children of <Router> must have a `path` or `default` prop, or be a `<Redirect>`. None found on element type `" + element.type + "`") : invariant(false) : void 0;
  699 |
  700 |     !!(element.type === Redirect && (!element.props.from || !element.props.to)) ? process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? invariant(false, "<Redirect from=\"" + element.props.from + "\" to=\"" + element.props.to + "\"/> requires both \"from\" and \"to\" props when inside a <Router>.") : invariant(false) : void 0;
  701 |
```

What does this mean? Am I missing something? Is it because I'm using the development and not production environment, causing it to fail?

**Update**: Following the answer by Ferran, I modified my code as follows, refactoring `pages/index.js` to `pages/app/[...].js`

```js
// pages/app/[...].js
import { Router } from '@reach/router';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import * as React from 'react';

import Browse from '../../components/Browse';
import Upload from '../../components/Upload';

const AppPage = () => (
  <>
    <nav>
      <Link to "/app/browse">Browse Link</Link>
      <Link to "/app/upload">Upload Link</Link>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <Router basepath="/app">
        <Browse path="/browse">Browse</Browse>
        <Upload path="/upload">Upload</Upload>
      </Router>
    </main>
  </>
);

export default AppPage;
```

All other files remain unchanged. However, the error persists at `http://localhost:8000/app/` after clicking a link.

**Update**: Tried adding a `Home` route:

```js
// pages/app/[...].js
import { Router } from '@reach/router';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import * as React from 'react';

import Browse from '../../components/Browse';
import Home from '../../components/Home';
import Upload from '../../components/Upload';

const AppPage = () => (
  <>
    <nav>
      <Link to "/app/">Home Link</Link>
      <Link to "/app/browse">Browse Link</Link>
      <Link to "/app/upload">Upload Link</Link>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <Router basepath="/app">
        <Browse path="/browse">Browse</Browse>
        <Upload path="/upload">Upload</Upload>
        <Browse path="/">Home</Browse>
      </Router>
    </main>
  </>
);

export default AppPage;
```

Upon adding this in, the same error immediately triggered at `http://localhost:8000/app/`. After removing the `Home` route but not the `Link`, the page can load again. Clicking Home Link at this point doesn't trigger any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that your paths are not found by Gatsby. I think you only need to move your `app.js` in `src/pages/app/[...].js` (renaming the file to `[...].js`).

You can follow an official Gatsby example in their [GitHub](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/client-only-paths/src/pages/%5B...%5D.js). The code from Gatsby's docs suggests:

```
// src/pages/app/[...].js

import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Profile from "../components/Profile"
import Details from "../components/Details"
import Login from "../components/Login"
import Default from "../components/Default"
import PrivateRoute from "../components/PrivateRoute"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Router basepath="/app">
        <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/details" component={Details} />
        <Login path="/login" />
        <Default path="/" />
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default App
```

The `[...].js` notation is using the [File System Route API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/), which is marking any dynamic segment of the URL after `/app` (because of the folder structure, `app/[...].js`).

Comment: See my update above. I tried updating the code as you suggested, but the error persists.

Comment: Assuming that you fix your `Link` structure. Can you confirm that you can't navigate using directly `/browse`, `/app/browse` etc?

Comment: Yeah, `Link` code is the same as what's shown above in my question. Nope, going directly to the endpoints didn't work. Same error.

Comment: Try to remove the `children` and leave the component like `<Upload path="/upload"/>` (self-closing). Since it's not a link, it just renders what matches better the `window.location`

Comment: It works now! How strange, you can't seem to treat routes as normal components with inner text or other nested content.

Comment: It's because whatever is wrapped inside a component is treated as a `children` (`props.children`) of that component. Since in the end, it's a route, it can't have children. I'm glad we finally figured it out. :)